# Is my laptop bricked?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, firmware

Have a *Lenovo Thinkpad* 470p running *18.04*. There was a notification a few days ago about a firmware update that I'd never seen before, but even after clicking install it claimed I needed to do the firmware update so I assumed it didn't work.

Today I rebooted for updates/kernel patches and it started beeping at me that I assume was some sort of thermal warning. It wasn't responding to holding the power button down, so I pulled the battery before it caught fire or exploded or whatever.

now it just comes up to a blank screen (no display or backlight), keys unresponsive, even <kbd>capslock</kbd> / <kbd>fnlock</kbd> don't trigger lights. No sounds, no bios screen. The only indication that it's on is a green light, and a beeping sounded

Am I done with this laptop? Is there a way to reset to factory firmware?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The beeps denote an error code. You can look up the error based on the number of beeps. Please [edit] your question to add the error.

Comment: It's no longer beeping, but it was like three or four beeps (one every five seconds or so) followed by two quick (1 second pauses) beeps before I pulled the battery out.

Comment: Here you can find BIOS update boot CD: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t470p/downloads

Comment: I am not sure whether the beeps indicate a bad memory error.

Comment: A colleague here has just bricked a laptop. We only discovered later that beeps indicated that BIOS was being flashed, and that power should not have been removed. Too bad that Ubuntu is pushing BIOS updates in such a dodgy way.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo provides a document that describes troubleshooting options based on various beep patterns and related symptoms.

Your problem might not be related to Ubuntu, even though you might have downloaded the firmware update via an Ubuntu tool.

If you turn your laptop back on, carefully note the symptoms and match them with Lenovo's guide:

"Beep and no beep symptoms - ThinkPad General"
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht035729